# Can't export a GEDCOM file from myheritage.com

Tags: gedcom, myheritage.com, data-transfer

I was trying to export a GEDCOM file following the instructions on [Can I export a Gedcom](https://faq.myheritage.com/en/article/can-i-export-a-gedcom-file-of-my-family-tree-from-my-family-site), but my list of possible actions does not show the link "Export to GEDCOM". Am I doing anything wrong?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only export a tree that you own from MyHeritage to Gedcom.

Looking at the screenshot, you don't appear to be the owner of that tree.